# Is it necessary to add “Any price “ option in budget category if on desktop user search with an open price range?

Tags: usability, filter, mobile-web, price-range, user-behaviour

[image]

Image for mobile web design. Not showing any price tag as wanted to make user perform a more focused search.The most widely searched ranges are upfront.

Answer (score 1):

#### N/A or Don't Care or Any or All

I find it very helpful to include some sort of "any" option. Otherwise I might think I **must** pick something. Some possibilities include:

- N/A = Not/Applicable
- Don't Care
- Any
- All

Which one works best may vary depending on the type of item being selected (price, brand, size, etc.) or the target audience.

#### Make It Clear

Include the "any" choice on the initial selection page. If you are using buttons, make it either the first or last button. If you are using a drop-down menu, make it the first (and default) choice.

#### Not Only for Price

This should apply to any/all selections where the user has the choice of "not selecting". That can include:

- Price
- Brand
- Size
- Special Features

Many systems will provide a series of checkboxes for various choices with the *implication* that not selecting any of the choices will result in "any" for that particular group of choices. That works well when you can show checkboxes and select one-or-more. But if it is "pick exactly one" then I like to include "any" (or equivalent) and make it the default so the user knows they don't have to pick something if they don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

Using pills may not be the optimum interaction:
- '+more' hides the *range* of options by default, making the user have to click more
- making the user select individual 'pills' is slow going if they have a wide budget range
- showing 'pills' that are unavailable may lead to 0 results, yet missing pills out of the scale may confuse the user :(

It might be easier to use a slider
or allow text input for min / max
or allow for both text input and slider scale

Setting the default scale to min and max will show the user what the cheapest and most expensive option is, and also display all available options.

here's airbnb's example:
[image]

hope that helps!